# Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$,$\mathcal{L}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$ Homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ and $\mathcal{L}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$ explain why $\{X,\mathcal{T}\}$ and $\{Y,\mathcal{L}\}$ are not homeomorhpic.

My reason was that $f(\{a,b,c\})$ would be a three element $\mathcal{L}$-open set which does not exist thus they are not homeomorphic

Is there something else I should be mentioning or does this suffice?

Comment: Looks about right to me. You might want to go into more detail though.

Answer (score 1):

That’s fine, though I think that it would be easier to focus on the isolated point $a$ of $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$, and it wouldn’t hurt to add a little detail explaining why the lack of an open set of equal cardinality makes them non-homeomorphic. I’ll illustrate what I mean with the open set $\{a\}\in\mathscr{T}$, but you can do it as well with $\{a,b,c\}$.

Suppose that $h:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism from $\langle X,\mathscr{L}\rangle$ to $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$; $\{a\}\in\mathscr{T}$, so $h^{-1}[\{a\}]\in\mathscr{L}$. But $h$ is a bijection, so $|h^{-1}[\{a\}]|=1$, and there is no one-element set in $\mathscr{L}$. This contradiction shows that no such $h$ can exist.

You could also note that $|\mathscr{T}|\ne|\mathscr{L}|$, though in order to use that you should prove that if $h:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism, then the map $H:\mathscr{T}\to\mathscr{L}:U\mapsto h[U]$ is a bijection.